# the multiplication result is always zero because of pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, multiplication

I am trying to write a program that takes two integers from the user and assigns them to pointers, and then passes those pointers to the function to multiply them and print the result. However the output is always 0. I'm a beginner and I'm failing to understand what I'm doing wrong. Help is appreciated. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x, y, m;

void point(int *xPtr, int *yPtr);

int main()
{
    int *xPtr, *yPtr;
    
    printf("Enter two integers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    point(&x, &y);

    m = (*xPtr)*(*yPtr);

    xPtr = &m;

    printf("The result is %d", *xPtr);

    return 0;
}

void point(int *xPtr, int *yPtr)
{
    xPtr = &x;
    yPtr = &y;
}
```

Comment: please refer [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for better understanding of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *main* the variables *xPtr* and *yPtr* are never initialized

the assignments in *point* are local and without consequence out of *point*, if you want to modify the variables having the same name in *main* you can do :

```
void point(int **xPtr, int **yPtr)
{
    *xPtr = &x;
    *yPtr = &y;
}
```

also changing the declaration of *point* of course, and change the call in *main* to be :

```
point(&xPtr, &yPtr);
```

> ... However the output is always 0

I don't think you have any output with the program you give because you very probably cannot reach the print, you deference non initialized pointers, the behavior is undefined and generally catastrophic like a segmentation fault

---

Modifying your program :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x, y, m;

void point(int **xPtr, int **yPtr);

int main()
{
    int *xPtr, *yPtr;
    
    printf("Enter two integers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    point(&xPtr, &yPtr);

    m = (*xPtr)*(*yPtr);

    xPtr = &m;

    printf("The result is %d", *xPtr);

    return 0;
}

void point(int **xPtr, int **yPtr)
{
    *xPtr = &x;
    *yPtr = &y;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter two integers: 
2 3
The result is 6pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==5992== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5992== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5992== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5992== Command: ./a.out
==5992== 
Enter two integers: 
2 3
The result is 6==5992== 
==5992== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5992==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5992==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 2,048 bytes allocated
==5992== 
==5992== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5992== 
==5992== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==5992== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that better :

- to check *scanf* returns 2 to know if the inputs was valid,
- to print a final `\n` because as you can be above the result is not readable executing your program in a terminal,
- to compile with high warning level and take into account the generating warnings

About the last remark and using your version of the code :

```
 pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall cc.c
 cc.c: In function ‘main’:
 cc.c:16:10: warning: ‘xPtr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
      m = (*xPtr)*(*yPtr);
          ~^~~~~~
 cc.c:16:18: warning: ‘yPtr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
      m = (*xPtr)*(*yPtr);
                 ~^~~~~~
```

If anyway I execute it under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==7143== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7143== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7143== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7143== Command: ./a.out
==7143== 
1 2Enter two integers: 

==7143== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==7143==    at 0x104BC: main (cc.c:16)
==7143== 
==7143== Invalid read of size 4
==7143==    at 0x104BC: main (cc.c:16)
==7143==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7143== 
==7143== 
==7143== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7143==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==7143==    at 0x104BC: main (cc.c:16)
==7143==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7143==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7143==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7143==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7143==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7143== 
==7143== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7143==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7143==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 2,048 bytes allocated
==7143== 
==7143== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7143== 
==7143== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==7143== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==7143== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Erreur de segmentation
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Nice answer! May I know if we ever need to use valgrind for a program if we never allocate any memory on heap?

Comment: @jarvis  to dereference can be illegal without any dynamic allocation etc ;-) To use it in an answer is a way to warn the OP about its existence

Comment: sorry im new to this site and didnt know abt it

Comment: @uwuuwu no problem, and happy new year ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are modifying the pointers themselves, you need to pass the pointers to these pointers (and pass the addresses of your pointers when you call the function):

```
point(&xPtr, &yPtr);
```

Define your function like this:

```
void point(int **xPtr, int **yPtr) {
    *xPtr = &x;
    *yPtr = &y;
}
```

Don't forget to change the declaration as well

```
void point(int **xPtr, int **yPtr);
```